# Rename project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I started a Windows Phone 7 application some time ago but didn't provide it with a sensible name when I started. That's why my project is called "WindowsPhoneApplication1" at the moment. Is there an easy way to rename my project to a more sensible name?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the title of the application in the Properties pages. Double click the Properties node in Solution Explorer and you'll get a page like this (note that the Application tab, on the left, is selected):

[image: Image showing application title and assembly name options]

As you can see you can change the default namespace (the one that encapsulates all classes if you have classes inside files without an explicit namespace), assembly name, and also the **Title of the application** which is what I think you're asking about.

Comment: It certainly doesn't mean "duplicate the properties twice"! :D Thanks for the heads-up :) fixed